# How to edit an Excel file with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with a lot of data. I know how to read it and manipulate it, but I don't know how to edit the file.
I wrote that:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("datas2.xlsx", usecols = "AT, AU")

## Q1
for i in range(2, len(df1)):
    if df1.iloc(1)[1][i] != 0:
        df1.iloc(1)[0][i] = 'D2'
    else:
        df1.iloc(1)[0][i] = 'D3'

df1.to_excel("test_stage.xlsx")
```

The problem is, it created a new excel file with only the columns I used in my df1 variable. Instead I would like to edit those columns in the original file.

Hoping someone can help me

Comment: Won't happen with pandas. Use openpyxl for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/)?

It lets you manipulate the excel file/sheet/cells by writing code in python! Pandas cannot do that.

After you installed xlwings and the addin in excel, you could write something like that in your Jupyter Notebook and directly manipulate your excel workbook:

```
import xlwings as xw #Import the package

book=xw.Book("YourBooksName.xlsx") #save your workbook as book, insert the name of the workbook if it is located in the same path as your Notebook, otherwise insert the path
sheet=book.sheets[0]               #save your excelsheet as sheet
for i in range(2, len(df1)):       

    if sheet.range((i,1)).value != 0: #this will check the value in the actual cell in the sheet
    
       sheet.range((i,1)).value= "D2" #it writes the value in the wanted cell
   else:
       sheet.range((i,1)).value= "D3"
```

Comment: Ok I'll check if it works thank you !